# Could a group embed normally in another group in which any automorphism is attained by conjugation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

## Problem

Suppose $G$ is a group. Can we always find a group $\tilde G$, such that $G$ is a normal subgroup of $\tilde G$, i.e. $G\triangleleft\tilde G$, and for each automorphism $\sigma\in\operatorname{Aut}G$ of $G$, there's an inner automorphism $\tau_g(x)=gxg^{-1}\,(g\in\tilde G)$ of $\tilde G$ that coincides with $\sigma$ on $G$, i.e. $\left.\tau_g\right\vert_G=\sigma$?

## Background

It's known that $K\triangleleft H$, $H\triangleleft G$ doesn't generally imply $K\triangleleft G$. A counterexample is furnished manywhere. However, if $K$ is [characteristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_subgroup#Transitivity) in $H$, we have $K\triangleleft G$. My problem is somewhat inverse of that: under what condition $\forall G(H\triangleleft G)\colon K\triangleleft G$? Is the characteristic condition necessary?

Comment: Hint: Think about direct limit of HNN extensions with the edge group G.

Comment: Or just take the *holomorph* of $G$, which is defined to be the semidirect product $G \rtimes {\rm Aut}(G)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sounds good. Could you please write a complete answer? (I'm not familiar with these concepts, but after a glance at wikipedia, it seems right.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any group $G$, the *holomorph* of $G$ is defined to be the semidirect product $G \rtimes {\rm Aut}(G)$ of $G$ with its automorphism group.

The elements are $\{(g,\sigma) \mid g \in G,\sigma \in {\rm Aut}(G) \}$

with the multiplication defined by $(g_1,\sigma_1)(g_2,\sigma_2)=(g_1\sigma_1(g_2),\sigma_1\sigma_2)$.

$G$ is isomorphic to the normal subgroup $\{(g,1) \mid g \in G \}$, and the automorphisms $\sigma$ of $G$ is induced by conjugation by $(1,\sigma)$. Check that

$(1,\sigma)(g,1)(1,\sigma^{-1})=(\sigma(g),1)$.

Comment: Does the terminology have anything to do with holomorphic functions?

Comment: Is there any intuition on semi-direct products? I met it in many situations, but all of them are algebraic constructions. I didn't see any other perspective, for example, from group action, or the viewpoint of transformation group.

Comment: I considered the embedding from $G$ into $\operatorname{Sym} G$. It's not normal, though. However, I didn't realize that the normalizer simply works.

Comment: Did you see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633286?