# How many conjugates does a regular permutation group have?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$. Consider $G$ as a regular subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$. What is the number of conjugate subgroups to $G$?

Comment: Does 'regular' have special significance here? Because $S_4$ has a normal subgroup of order $4$, which must only have one conjugate subgroup, but other subgroups of $S_4$ with order $4$ do have several conjugates. That is, please clarify what 'regular' means in this context. I can find some references on MO, but it doesn't seem entirely clear what what we're dealing with.

Comment: _Regular_ means _transitive of order n._

Comment: The number of conjugates of a subgroup $G$ of $H$ is the index of its normalizer $N_H(G)$ in $H$. Now look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633286/holomorph-is-isomorphic-to-normalizer-of-subgroup-of-symmetric-group).

Comment: Using my last comment one should be able toarrive at the conclusion that the desired number is $\frac{(n-1)!}{|Aut(G)|}$.

Comment: @j.p.: I agree, thanks.