# Normalizer of the cyclic group in $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $G = S_n$ and $H = \langle (1,2,\ldots,n) \rangle.$ It is not too hard to see that $$C_G(H) = H.$$

What I am now wondering is, which group is $N_G(H)?$ Is there any way to determine that?

I guess the key is to use the fact that $$g (1,2,\ldots, n) g^{-1} = (g(1), \ldots, g(n))$$ but I don't see how to get the full answer just by this.

Comment: Here are a few hints to get you started. Let $h = (1,2,\ldots,n)$. By multipliying $g \in N_G(H)$ by and element of $H$, you can assume that $g(1)=1$. Now if $g(2) = 1+k$, then $ghg^{-1} = (1,1+k,\ldots)$ and, since this is a power of $h$,  it must be $h^k$ (which also maps $1$ to $1+k$). Since this induces an automorphism of $H$, $k$ and $n$ must be coprime. Conversely, if $k$ and $n$ are coprime then there is such a $g$.

Answer (score 12):

Consider the following bits/steps. I abbreviate $\alpha=(123\ldots n)$.

- If $g\in N_G(H)$, then $g\alpha g^{-1}\in H$, and $g\alpha g^{-1}$ must also have order $n$.
- Therefore $g\alpha g^{-1}=\alpha^k$ for some integer $k$, $\gcd(k,n)=1$.
- All the elements $\alpha^k$, $k$ as above, are conjugate in $S_n$.
- The elements $g$ such that $g\alpha g^{-1}=\alpha^k$, $k$ as above, form a coset of $C_G(H)=H$.
- The number of such cosets in $N_G(H)$ is thus given by the Euler totient function $\phi(n)$.
- $N_G(H)$ will be isomorphic to $C_n\rtimes Aut(C_n)$.

Comment: Seeing the Euler function was was surprising for me initially, but your explanations are lucid,! +1

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps it is worth noting the [more general fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633286/holomorph-is-isomorphic-to-normalizer-of-subgroup-of-symmetric-group), that if $H$ is a group of order $n$, and $\psi : H \to S_{n}$ is the regular representation, then $N_{S_{n}}(\psi(H))$ is isomorphic to the holomorph $H \rtimes \operatorname{Aut}(H)$ of $H$.